# Fragment gets destroyed everytime app is closed

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, android, android-pageradapter

So I have this app it has one main activity, 3 fragments controlled by a viewpager. So it is a Tabbed Application. I have one TabPagerAdapter which extends FragmentPagerAdapter and in this class getItem returns new fragment();

My second problem is that when I close my app the fragments which were all populated lose all their views and I have to refresh my listviews again. So is there any way in which I can make the fragment retain it's views and data on opening and closing of the app like the twitter and facebook apps where the feed is maintained to the last synced feed.

I have seen the answers where they say i should make a static initialize() method and call that in tabsadapter but since my data is in an Arraylist how would store this in a bundle ?

Can you provide sample code for this aswell ?

I'm sorry I know the question is very vague and I am asking for a huge answer but i am really stuck with this and cant find a suitable solution.

Comment: you should create files of your responses and save them into internal/external storage. later when app is opened check if these files are present and read and parse those files to load data again into your views. this is the general policy followed by every application.

Comment: Have you tried to extend FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Comment: Amrut thank you for that solution works great. Wonder why I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem was to as suggested by Amrut Bidri in the comments was to set up a file and then store the data in that and load from that when fragment is created.